# C# Binary tree Graphical/Visual control

Tags: c#, sql-server, binary, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have data in the MSSQL database and it is a binary tree. The users are connecting to each other as a binary tree network. I need to show them in a visual graphical view. Also, it should allow to search a username and load it as the root node to show the child nodes.

Is there a C#/.NET control or a code for this? Please, can you advise me on this? We built everything on the database using SQL, Stored procedures functions and views. So appreciate if you can tell me how to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are asking for. You need a .NET control for what exactly? Winforms, wince, WPF, something else? Could you provide example data? How is the username involved? And the rest of your model?
What have you tried so far? What is not working?

Comment: See codeproject : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/334773/Graphical-BinaryTrees

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It is a website page. I can ask to pass the data to the tree as an SQL or SP if I have implemented it on .NET control. (ascx+cs)
Please forget about the information. It is just the user details. I just want to show the users with their usernames in a binary tree.

If there is a user control, that would be much easier. But if you know a sample code, then I can use it easily with modifications. I want to load the binary tree for the given userID. That will be the root node. Need to load the other child nodes in the binary tree in a nice attractive way on the web page.